# Environtment variable via github secrets

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a scala repo on github with has the scala work flow in `scala.yml`. One of my test requires a special key to be available. But I can't hard code it into source code because of privacy reasons. So, I added the key to `Secrets` section in `Settings`. The section states

```
Secrets are environment variables that are encrypted and only exposed to selected actions. Anyone with collaborator access to this repository can use these secrets in a workflow.

Secrets are not passed to workflows that are triggered by a pull request from a fork.
```

But when I do try to get the key in my code(in the test) it comes out as blank.

```
System.getenv("MY_KEY") //MY_KEY is added to the Secrets in Settings of the repo
```

Also, this workflow is NOT triggered by a pull request from a fork.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to set it in the set it in the environment variable your work flow as given [here](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets). If the variable name in `Secrets` is `MY_KEY` then in the work flow you can access it as `{{ secrets.MY_KEY }}`

Example

```
    - name: Run tests
      env:
        MY_KEY: ${{ secrets.MY_KEY }}
      run: sbt test
```

This will set the environment variable `MY_KEY` and can be accessed via `System.getenv("MY_KEY")`

Comment: `System.getenv("MY_KEY")` returns `***`